Using anchor_client with tokio
I'm trying to invoke a transaction with anchor_client from a tokio context. Here's how I'm doing it:
    let pid = Keypair::new().pubkey();
    let payer = Rc::new(Keypair::new());
    let client = Client::new_with_options(Cluster::Localnet, &payer, CommitmentConfig::processed());
    let program = client.program(pid).unwrap();
    // `Initialize` parameters.
    let dummy_a = Keypair::new();
    let dummy_b = Keypair::new();

    tokio::spawn(async {
        program
            .request()
            .accounts(CompositeUpdate {
                foo: Foo {
                    dummy_a: dummy_a.pubkey(),
                },
                bar: Bar {
                    dummy_b: dummy_b.pubkey(),
                },
            })
            .args(composite_instruction::CompositeUpdate {
                dummy_a: 1234,
                dummy_b: 4321,
            })
            .send()
            .await
            .unwrap();

        println!("Composite success!");
    });

Unfortunately this gives me the error
error[E0277]: `Rc<solana_sdk::signature::Keypair>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/nonblocking.rs:73:18
    |
73  |       tokio::spawn(async {
    |  _____------------_^
    | |     |
    | |     required by a bound introduced by this call
74  | |         program
75  | |             .request()
76  | |             .accounts(CompositeUpdate {
...   |
92  | |         println!("Composite success!");
93  | |     });
    | |_____^ `Rc<solana_sdk::signature::Keypair>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `anchor_client::Program<&Rc<solana_sdk::signature::Keypair>>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `Rc<solana_sdk::signature::Keypair>`, which is required by `{async block@src/nonblocking.rs:73:18: 93:6}: Send`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `&Rc<solana_sdk::signature::Keypair>`

What I've tried:

Switching from an Rc to an Arc
Switching from async to async move
Putting all the client and program declaration stuff inside tokio::spawn
Making my own type like in this question. The answer to this question says The best approach as of now is to just create the Signer in each thread separately, instead of having a single signer being used across threads., but I couldn't really figure out how to change my code accordingly.

For anyone wanting to recreate this MRE locally: This MRE is based on https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/client/example/src/nonblocking.rs. The only change I made was adding tokio::spawn (since I need this in my own code) and enabling the async feature for anchor_client.
Thanks in advance!

It turns out this was a fundamental limitation in anchor_client that couldn't be worked around without having to fork anchor. Fortunately this PR was merged recently which adds support with the async feature flag, so this will be supported at the next minor release (presumably 0.31.0 since it's a breaking change).

We kinda fight with this as well. Despite we do not have the same way of working with tokio these are my observations:
First, I assume you work with solana_client::nonblocking as it's an async example.
Another thing we do is to enable async feature of the Anchor client in Cargo.toml in dependencies
anchor-client = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["async"] }

I haven't studied the "async" feature and I don't know what exactly it does and how it influences the behaviour, nor if it's default ¯_(ツ)_/¯,  but as it sounds it does something with asynchronous handling I use it :-)
For creating the program we currently do:
use anchor_client::{Client, Cluster, DynSigner, Program};
use solana_client::nonblocking::rpc_client::RpcClient;

let payer = Arc::new(DynSigner(Arc::new(Keypair::new())));

// rpc_client: Arc<RpcClient>
let program = Client::new_with_options(
  Cluster::from_str(&rpc_client.url())?,
  payer,
  rpc_client.commitment(),
)
.program(ID)?;

But all that usage of DynSigner comes from the fact we wanted to use generic Signer to work with the HW wallet as welll. Which does not work properly and I believe it's because the Signer is not Sized. I consider it could be solved with PR https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/34984 when available in Solana Rust SDK.
You can check our code at:
https://github.com/marinade-finance/validator-bonds/blob/main/common-rs/src/lib.rs
I believe the Rc could not be a good choice when used in async code (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#thread-safety).
But it could be ok if used only for reading.
As you don't need to work with the Signer(!) then why not to work directly with Keypair wrapped in Arc ? I.e., passing the Arc<Keypair> and not the reference? Would that work?
let payer = Arc::new(Keypair::new());
let client = Client::new_with_options(Cluster::Localnet, payer.clone(), CommitmentConfig::processed());


Thanks a lot for your answer! I switched to Arc and passed the Arc<Keypair> directly like you did, but unfortunately still am getting the same error. And yes, I'm using anchor_client with the async feature. I don't have a direct dependency on solana_client::nonblocking anywhere, but I'm guessing anchor_client does under the hood since I'm using the async feature.
I think the problem is tokio wants it to have the trait Send which solana keypair doesn't have.

If it does not work in any way then probably the easiest "hack" is to serialize the keypair to JSON string (https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/0d34a1a160129c4293dac248e14231e9e773b4ce/sdk/src/signer/keypair.rs#L188), working with String through all the sending tokio code parts and then deserialize when needed to sign and creating the new Program instance at that place?

This unfortunately doesn't work either, I've tried creating the keypair, client & program instance inside the tokio::spawn call but it gives the same error in that case too :(

Ok, I cannot help myself I spent a bit some time on checking what's going on. If you haven't got further I think that in current time the way to go is to create Transaction beforehand it is used within the spawn async block.
I have a working (hopefully) example here: https://github.com/ochaloup/anchor/blob/testing-tokio/client/example/src/nonblocking.rs#L133
I figured out that all is about the Signer that's not Send. Because the Anchor client works with Signer there is no way to wrap it right to be usable in async code until Signer (as the inner struct) is not configured properly.

Maybe our wrapper for transaction building could be helpful(?)
https://github.com/marinade-finance/solana-transaction-builder/blob/main/libs/solana-transaction-builder/src/prepared_transaction.rs

I had an issue where I was using Keypair and NullSigner to sign a transaction on a tokio::task::spawn instance.
The issue was that I couldn't put @n-kuria 's struct in an array because it couldn't implement Sized.
My fix was to put @n-kuria 's implementation in an enum
let signers: [&SendableKeypair; 2] = [&self.config.backend_authority, &self.config.sol_wallet];

pub enum SendableKeypair {
    Keypair([u8;64]),
    NullSigner(Pubkey)
}

pub trait SendableSigner: Send + Sync + Signer + Sized {}

impl SendableSigner for SendableKeypair {}

impl Signer for SendableKeypair {/*a similar implementation*/}


@chalda's approach (described here and here) is the best solution I've found.
Step 1: Create a Sendable Keypair that can be used from Tokio
use anchor_client::solana_sdk::pubkey::Pubkey;
use anchor_client::solana_sdk::signature;
use anchor_client::solana_sdk::signature::Signer;
use solana_sdk::signature::Signature;
use solana_sdk::signature::SignerError;
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Display;

/// A tokio compatible wrapper for `anchor_client::solana_sdk::signature::Keypair`
///
/// The standard Keypair is not Sendable and cannot be used from
/// within a Tokio runtime.
///
/// This Keypair works by storing the keypair bytes and only
/// rebuilding the original anchor_client Keypair when inside
/// the synchronous context of the Signer trait
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Keypair {
    keypair: [u8; 64],
}

trait SendableSigner: Send + Sync + Signer {}
impl SendableSigner for Keypair {}

impl Display for Keypair {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let keypair = signature::Keypair::from_bytes(&self.keypair).map_err(|_| fmt::Error)?;
        write!(f, "{}", keypair.to_base58_string())
    }
}

impl Keypair {
    pub fn new<T: AsRef<signature::Keypair>>(keypair: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            keypair: keypair.as_ref().to_bytes(),
        }
    }

    pub fn from_keypair(keypair: &signature::Keypair) -> Self {
        Self {
            keypair: keypair.to_bytes(),
        }
    }

    pub fn from_base58_string(s: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            keypair: signature::Keypair::from_base58_string(s).to_bytes(),
        }
    }
}

impl Signer for Keypair {
    fn try_pubkey(&self) -> std::result::Result<Pubkey, SignerError> {
        // Convert the stored keypair bytes back to a Keypair
        let keypair = signature::Keypair::from_bytes(&self.keypair)
            .map_err(|e| SignerError::Custom(e.to_string()))?;

        // Return the public key of the keypair
        Ok(keypair.pubkey())
    }

    fn try_sign_message(&self, message: &[u8]) -> std::result::Result<Signature, SignerError> {
        // Convert the stored keypair bytes back to a Keypair
        let keypair = signature::Keypair::from_bytes(&self.keypair)
            .map_err(|e| SignerError::Custom(e.to_string()))?;

        // Sign the message with the keypair
        Ok(keypair.try_sign_message(message)?)
    }

    fn is_interactive(&self) -> bool {
        // This method should return true if the signer requires user interaction to sign messages.
        // In this case, we assume that it does not require user interaction, so we return false.
        false
    }
}

Step 2: Build a transaction
use anchor_client::solana_sdk::signature;

let pid = signature::Keypair::new().pubkey();
let payer = Rc::new(Keypair::from_keypair(signature::Keypair::new()));
let client = Client::new_with_options(Cluster::Localnet, &payer, CommitmentConfig::processed());
let program = client.program(pid).unwrap();

// `Initialize` parameters.
let dummy_a = Keypair::from_keypair(signature::Keypair::new());
let dummy_b = Keypair::from_keypair(signature::Keypair::new());

let instructions = program
    .request()
    .accounts(CompositeUpdate {
        foo: Foo {
            dummy_a: dummy_a.pubkey(),
        },
        bar: Bar {
            dummy_b: dummy_b.pubkey(),
        },
    })
    .args(composite_instruction::CompositeUpdate {
        dummy_a: 1234,
        dummy_b: 4321,
    })
    .instructions()
    .map_err(...)?;

let (blockhash, _) = program
    .async_rpc()
    .get_latest_blockhash_with_commitment(CommitmentConfig::processed())
    .await
    .map_err(...)?;

// Create a signed transaction
let tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &instructions,
    Some(&dummy_a.clone().pubkey()),
    // assume two signers
    &[&dummy_a.clone(), &dummy_b.clone()],
    blockhash,
);

Step 3: Submit the transaction with the solana_client library:
use solana_client::nonblocking::rpc_client::RpcClient;
let solana_client = RpcClient::new_with_commitment(provider_url.clone());
solana_client.send_and_confirm_transaction(&tx).await;


Thanks, but this doesn't use tokio::spawn, which is where my problem lies.
